# how to get text in a row on clicking corresponding button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have added HTML5 buttons & text in a webpage thro' DOM methods. What i need is, when i clicked a particular button, it's corresponding Btn_ID & corresponding text should be shown in alert. I am getting corresponding Btn_ID, but i'm not able to take its text.

My Code is;

```
<head>
    <style>
    .tbls {
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
    }
    .Rows {
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
    .Btn {
        height:40px;
        width:70px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='contnt'></div>
</body>
<script>
var arry = ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5"];
var container = document.getElementById('contnt');
for(var j = 0; j < arry.length; j++) {
    var tbls = document.createElement('table');
    tbls.className = 'tbls';
    var Rows = document.createElement('tr');
    Rows.className = 'Rows';
    var Column = document.createElement('td');
    var questionlist = document.createTextNode(arry[j]);
    Column.appendChild(questionlist);
    var Btn = document.createElement('button');
    Btn.id = j;
    Btn.className = 'Btn';
    Btn.innerHTML = 'SUBMIT';
    Btn.onclick = function () {
        alert(this.id);
        alert(this.parentElement.questionlist);
    }
    Column.appendChild(Btn);
    Rows.appendChild(Column);
    tbls.appendChild(Rows);
    container.appendChild(tbls);
}
</script>
```

Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/9je7N/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to `alert` Name1 if the first `submit` is clicked?

```
Btn.onclick = function() { 
   alert(this.id);
   alert(this.parentElement.firstChild.nodeValue); 
}

//this.parentElement = Your table cell
//this.parentElement.firstChild = text node (questionlist)
//this.parentElement.firstChild.nodeValue = text node's value //Name1, Name2
```

Update:

To get the first text node within the `td` element

```
Btn.onclick = function() { 
   alert(this.id);
   var children = this.parentElement.childNodes;
    var text;
    for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i ++) {
        if(children[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            text = children[i].nodeValue;
            break;
        }
    }
   alert(text); 
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H4fbp/)

[**Updated jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H4fbp/2/)

Comment: if i added a new button/div components before adding the questiontext to the column,this code gives null value. What i have to do in this case.

Comment: This code relied on the text being present at the `firstChild` position. Please check the updated fiddle.